# Multiple rules for ::selection and ::-moz-selection (and user-select?)

Tags: css, selection

I have website, where I first set

```
::selection
{
    background: transparent;
}
::-moz-selection
{
    background: transparent;
}
*
{
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -khtml-user-select: none; 
    -webkit-user-select: none; 
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
 }
```

( Just for the artistic effect, not because I'd be trying to prevent people from copying something. )

But then, later on, I want the user to be able to select text from a textarea..

I was able to make the selection visible again, with

```
#commentarea::selection
{
    background: #070707;
}
#commentarea::-moz-selection
{
    background: #070707;
}
#commentarea
{
    -moz-user-select: element; 
    -khtml-user-select: element; 
    -webkit-user-select: element; 
    -o-user-select: element;
    user-select: element;
}
```

but if the user selects something from the textarea, it cannot be unselected by clicking somewhere. You can only unselect the text by moving the caret ( with arrow keys ).

Why is that? And how can I prevent this?

Comment: I'm only able to replicate this in Firefox (13), and I'm only able to select text by moving the caret (Shift + Arrow). With that being the case, it almost makes sense that I have to move the caret to unselect it.

Comment: Be very careful combining two experimental and *very broken* implementations in CSS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
#commentarea
{
    -moz-user-select: element; 
    -khtml-user-select: element; 
    -webkit-user-select: element; 
    -o-user-select: element;
    user-select: element;
}
```

to

```
#commentarea {
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -khtml-user-select: text;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -o-user-select: text;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dWjPQ/1/

Comment: in google chrome and internet explorer it works, it doesnt work only in mozilla

Comment: For Firefox, change the * { -moz-user-select: none; } to * { -moz-user-select: -moz-none; }

Comment: `-o-user-select` does nothing: Opera hasn't implemented it. Also, `-ms-user-select` now exists for IE 10, so you may want to add that.

Answer (score 2):

Enve's answer was correct.. for browsers other than Firefox ( 13.0 at least ).

To people who have the same problem:

In the universal selector ( `*` ), you must use `-moz-user-select: -moz-none;`, instead of `-moz-user-select: none;`.
This will fix the problem.

Comment: Ha. Seems like you found the solution exactly when I did. :)